# Existence of a certain R-module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with identity and $A,B,C$ be $R-$modules. Let $f:A\rightarrow C, g:B\rightarrow C$ be $R$-module homomorphisms such that $g$ is surjective. Does there exist an $R-$module homomorphism $h:A\rightarrow B$ such that the following diagram is commutative:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Consider $A = C$ and $f$ the identity. Then the question becomes whether $g$ admits a section.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you. This wasnt a good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If this were true for all such $B,g,C$, then $A$ would be called a projective module.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes if and only if the $\rm R$-module $\rm A$ is projective. And it is precisely the definition of a projective module.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: How do you define a projective module?